# How to get array value in seperate combobox

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I want to get the array value in separate comboboxes using JavaScript and PHP. Suppose i have array like

> 0:{"id":"none","name":"none"},1:{"id":"none","name":"none"},2:{"id":"write","name":"write"}

I want that 0 index array will show in first combo box, 1 index array will show in 2nd combo box and so on, all combo boxes having same name. But when I done it is showing all arrays in one combo box .Here is my code

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "none",
  "name": "none"
}, {
  "id": "none",
  "name": "none"
}, {
  "id": "write",
  "name": "write"
}]

$.each(data, function(i, item) {

  $('#modules').append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="modules"></select>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you edit to show exact output your looking for?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please update to reflect the issue

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcXaK.png here is the link of image ,it is my output

Comment: What is the problem? The code you have creates a dropdown. What is wrong with it? I you want 3 dropdowns you need to first add a select to the div

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i think you want to show data in dropdown
just make sure your array is in correct format.

```
var data = [{"id":"none","name":"none"},                
                        {"id":"none","name":"none"},        
        {"id":"write","name":"write"}];

$.each(data,function(i,item){
   $('#modules').append('<option value="'+data[i].id+'">'+data[i].name+'</option>');  });




$('.modules').eq(i).append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');
```

Comment: $('.modules').eq(i).append('<option value="' + data[i].id + '">' + data[i].name + '</option>');

Comment: What did you actually do?

Comment: @Akhilesh yes. I cannot see any difference from what OP had in the array I created in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to achieve this using plain JavaScript, please see below snippet with desired output - select dropdown with text from objects in array populating the options.

```js
var data = [{
  "id": "none",
  "name": "none"
}, {
  "id": "none",
  "name": "none"
}, {
  "id": "write",
  "name": "write"
}]


function comboBox(data) {
    const select = document.getElementById('modules')
    data.map(object => {
     let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = object.id;
        option.text = object.id;
        select.appendChild(option);  
    })
}

comboBox(data);
```

```html
<select id="modules"></select>
```

Comment: He is using jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You want 3 dropdowns?

```js
var data = { 
  "one":   [{ "id": "none", "name": "none 1" }, { "id": "none", "name": "none 1" }, { "id": "write", "name": "write 1" }], 
  "two":   [{ "id": "none", "name": "none 2" }, { "id": "none", "name": "none 2" }, { "id": "write", "name": "write 2" }], 
  "three": [{ "id": "none", "name": "none 3" }, { "id": "none", "name": "none 3" }, { "id": "write", "name": "write 3" }]
}

$.each(data, function(i, item) {
  var $sel = $("<select/>", {
    "name": "data"
  });
  $.each(item, function(i, selItem) {
    $sel.append('<option value="' + selItem.id + '">' + selItem.name + '</option>')
  });
  $('#modules').append($sel);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="modules"></div>
```